# neo4j graph find all path from parent to each child without relationship

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, path, hierarchy

I want to print all path present form parent node to child node for entire trees present in graph. Database contains Sr manager as root node.Database contains only single tree maintained in hierarchy there is no graph. Only 2 types of nodes exists Employee and Position. Employee node is connected to other employee node by :boss_of  where as each employee has only one Position node connected with :has_power relationship. there is **no connection/relationship** between different positions. I want to print all paths present in following manner. **Sr manager will always be present at the start of path** Please see diagram.

```
Sr Manager 
Sr Manager -> Manager 
Sr Manager -> Manager -> jr developer
Sr Manager -> Manager -> sr developer
Sr Manager -> Manager -> tester
Sr Manager -> Manager -> tester -> BA
Sr Manager -> Manager -> tester -> BA -> jrBA 
Sr Manager -> Manager -> tester -> BA -> jrBA -> content writer[enter
```

and so on .....

Apologies! there is a bit change in the graph structure there is one more type of node conencted to Employee labeled as Domain so in graph there are 3 types of nodes present Employee, Position and Domain , whereas both Position and Domain are conencted to Employee with :has_power and :has_ref relationship resp and there is no relation between Position and Domain

Here are the examples
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVv9H.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iql7r.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you need to match on all of your hierarchies (starting with the root, which doesn't have any bosses), then for each node in the hierarchy replace it with its position, then get the distinct results. Something like this:

```
MATCH path = (top:Employee)-[:boss_of*0..]->(emp)
WHERE NOT ()-[:boss_of]->(top)
WITH DISTINCT [node in nodes(path) | [(position)-[:has_power]->(node) | position][0]] as positions
ORDER BY size(positions) DESC
```

This uses a list comprehension to change each element of the nodes in the path, and a pattern comprehension to match out from the employee to the position the employee holds and project that position to the list.

If you want just the textual results from the list, then you'll need to access whatever property (name?) you're using to store the position name.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the answer! sorry but i am very new to this Cypher. Here position is variable or Label?? because actual name of label is 'Position'. So what should be returned here  so that each Position parent can have list of childrens in front of it?? so basically i want 2 columns in result col1 will have  parent name and col2 will have list of it's children. and yes property of position name is 'name'

Comment: In this case `position` is a variable, referring to the node that is connected to the `node` (the :Employee nodes from your earlier match) by the `:has_power` relationship. Because your graph structure only has :Position nodes connected by :Employee nodes by this relationship, we don't need to actually filter by the label of the node, it's just enough to know that across that kind of relationship is the node we want, and we create a list of the positions from the connected employees.

Comment: Can you provide an example result so I can better understand how you want the returned format? Right now the Sr Management node is always at the start of the path, do you always want that node at the start? Or do you want the hierarchy as well? And do you want just the immediate children, or all reachable children at any depth as specified in your example results above?

Comment: since sr manger is parent of all nodes it will be present at the root node and then relevant nodes so obviously for each path sr manager will be present at the start.

Comment: Apologies! there is a bit change in the graph structure there is one more type of node conencted to Employee labeled as Domain so in graph there are 3 types of nodes present Employee, Position and Domain , whereas both Position and Domain are conencted to Employee with :has_power and :has_ref relationship resp and there is no relation between Position and Domain .

Comment: also your query return inconsisten results, I mean not every path contains nodes from the sr manger(root) node

Comment: Again can you please update your question with some sample desired output? At this point I'm not clear on what your desired output is supposed to be, and I can't give any relevant advice until that's clarified.

Comment: Can you also give an example of the bad output? This query should always use nodes without a boss as the start. In the graph you gave, only Sr Manager doesn't have a boss.